# SQL query executing but not affecting row

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

So im having some trouble with my database right now, I can't seem to update a variable, Im just looking to do a simple "UPDATE" query, this is what it looks like:

[MY table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o22L.png)

So very simple table and all I am looking to do is update the "Sent" column from no to yes.

I've been using UPDATE but for some reason this dosn't work, no syntax error just says 0 rows affected and nothing changes...

```
UPDATE `numbers` SET `Sent`='True' WHERE `fName`='John';
```

(Im hoping to change the sent value of all rows containing fName = John.... As you can see in my table John is a value in the database so this should work but for some reason doesn't) Could anyone explain why my statement is wrong and what I am not doing right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug this.  Start with the `select` query:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM numbers n
WHERE fName = 'John';
```

This should return no rows -- meaning that what you see is not what you got.  One common problem are invisible characters at the beginning, end, or both (often just spaces).  So you can try:

```
WHERE fName LIKE '%John'
WHERE fName LIKE 'John%'
WHERE fName LIKE '%John%'
```

Once you figure out what works, you can figure out what to use in the `UPDATE` or how to fix the data.

Comment: Thank you, problem was invisible chars, thanks for the debugging tips, will use them next time I get a problem!